# jQuery child selector: only select top level child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a multi level unordered list (`ul`, `li`):

```
<ul class="onlyme">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>bbb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I only want the first child elements of **ul.onlyme** to be selected. I am using the following jQuery to select them

```
$('ul.onlyme > li').click(function(){
    alert('bingo');
});
```

If I click `aaa` or `bbb`, the alert appears twice. What do I need to do to make sure it only selects the li's with: 'one' and 'two'?

Comment: what alerts appear if you change the alert line to : alert($(this).text());

Comment: I can't tell if you want to completely exclude the last `<li>` or only prevent it from triggering the alert twice. Different parts of your question suggest both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"What do I need to do to make sure it only selects the li's with: 'one' and 'two'?"*

If you mean you want to exclude `li` elements that have a nested `ul`...

```
$('ul.onlyme > li:not(:has(ul))').click(function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3TsNp/

Comment: nice solution. what i don't understand is why the lower level li's don't propagate their event

Comment: Your selector can be sped-up a lot. `$('.onlyme').children().not(':has(ul)')`. The less string-work that has to be done the better.

Comment: @Alp: They do, but there's no handler bound to those `li` elements since they were excluded from the initial DOM selection. Only the first two `li`s were selected, so only those two have handlers

Comment: @Jasper: I would agree with respect to using `:has()` since it's a non-standard selector. The rest of it will depend entirely on the browser that's running the selector.

Comment: @amnotiam Check-out this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-function-selectors-vs-strings (Note that my IE6 results had errors of about 50%).

Comment: @Jasper: Yes, that confirms what I said, no? The `:has()` selector is non-standard, and so will be very slow, but `$('.onlyme').children('li')` vs `$('.onlyme > li')` will be browser dependent.

Comment: I guess the point is that `$('.onlyme').children().not(':has(ul)');` is generally a third faster to twice as fast as `$('ul.onlyme > li:not(:has(ul))');`. Which I brought up since it's the suggested code in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead you can use `delegate` and attach a click handler only on the `ul` element passing `li` as element selector to listen to. Try this.

```
$('ul.onlyme').delegate('li', 'click', function(e){
    alert('bingo!');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgSqC/1/)**

`.delegate()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: That'll work well to make sure the nested ones don't fire the handler, but it seems from the question that OP only wants the first two `li` elements to trigger it. *"make sure it only selects the li's with: 'one' and 'two'?"* But the title doesn't really line up with that, so I'm not sure what's actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the nested `<ul>` element and it's children `<li>` elements are propagating the `click` event to their parent `<li>` elements which have the `click` event handler attached. If you stop the propagation of the nested elements you will only get an alert when you click directly on a top-level `<li>` element:

```
//bind click event handler to the top-level list-item elements
$('.onlyme').children('li').click(function(){
    alert('bingo');

//bind a click event handler to the lower-level list-items
}).find('li').click(function () {

    //simply return false to stop the propagation of this click event
    return false;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmpdr/

Notice I changed the `>` selector to the `.children()` function, the function will perform faster.

Comment: If you're going to bind a handler only to stop propagation, you could also do `.bind('click',false)`.

Comment: Interesting, I've never thought to do that. Can't say I've used an event handler to only return false though. Thanks.